# fixed aspect ratio in div, no matter the screen

Tags: css, media-queries

I have a div I would like to mantain aspect ratio 2:1 no matter the screen size and ratio are.

This is my choice (discarding other previous options)

```css
.mydiv{

    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    position: absolute;
    height: 50%;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
    this should be a fixed aspect ratio div
  </div
```

I tried media queries and this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_css_aspect_ratio.asp but it is not what I'm looking for because of the white padding space

Comment: set display: table-row

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Maintain the aspect ratio of a div with CSS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1495407/maintain-the-aspect-ratio-of-a-div-with-css)

Answer (score 1):

Set **`left`** and **`top`** property **`.mydiv`** to **`0`** and also set **`margin:0`** to body to remove the extra space.

***Stack Snippet***

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
}

.mydiv {
  background-color: red;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  height: 50%;
  left: 0;
  top: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">this should be a fixed aspect ratio div
  </div
```

I hope this will help you!

Answer (score 1):

try this

```css
.mydiv{

    background-color: red;
    width: 100vw;
    height: 50vh;
    position: absolute;
    left:0;
    right: 0;
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
    this should be a fixed aspect ratio div
  </div
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `padding-bottom` and choose the percentage according to your desired ratio

```css
.mydiv{
    background-color: red;
    width: 100%;
    padding-bottom: 50%;
    position: absolute;
}
```

```html
<div class="mydiv">
    this should be a fixed aspect ratio div
  </div
```